# Converting data with a start and end date to daily data in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, powerquery, alteryx

Hey I'm trying to convert data that has a start and end date into daily data by adding in daily date rows and splitting all metrics equally over the number of days. I recently found an example of someone doing it with Alteryx but I was wondering if a similar thing can be done in SSIS. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

https://vimeo.com/130300684

I have achieved this in Excel Power Query but still unsure how to do it in SSIS. First I get the datediff of start and end date + 1, then expand the rows between the dates then divide the metrics by the datediff.

I made it with a before and after to show the process of what I would like to achieve in SSIS. Random example data, its very rough.

Link to my Power Query/Excel here: https://ufile.io/b4e3z

Comment: It can probably be done.   Please add sample data and desired results to your question to make it clear.

Comment: Attached what I have done in Excel Power Query, just would like to do the same in SSIS